# CMFCPropertySheet "Page" resources are not resizing with dynamic layout

Tags: mfc, propertysheet

I am really confused. :(

Here is a new property sheet:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "resource.h"
#include "VisitsRotaMFCPropertySheet.h"


CVisitsRotaMFCPropertySheet::CVisitsRotaMFCPropertySheet()
    :CResizingMFCPropertySheet(_T("VisitsRota"), AFX_IDS_APP_TITLE, nullptr, 0)
{
    ConstructSheet();
}

CVisitsRotaMFCPropertySheet::~CVisitsRotaMFCPropertySheet()
{
}


BOOL CVisitsRotaMFCPropertySheet::OnInitDialog()
{
    BOOL bResult = CResizingMFCPropertySheet::OnInitDialog();

    m_Menu.LoadMenu(IDR_MENU);
    SetMenu(&m_Menu);

    return bResult;
}


void CVisitsRotaMFCPropertySheet::ConstructSheet()
{
    m_psh.dwFlags |= PSH_NOAPPLYNOW;

    AddPage(&m_ElderlyInfirmPage);
    AddPage(&m_ShepherdingPage);
}
```

It is derived from `CResizingMFCPropertySheet`. This is the source for that class:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/fzpfo4c3dpt6l51/ResizingMFCPropertySheet.cpp?dl=0

Now, I have two pages in this window. Here is one for the definitions:

```
IDD_PAGE_ELDERLY_INFIRM DIALOGEX 0, 0, 420, 202
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_CHILD | WS_CAPTION
CAPTION "Elderly && Infirm"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    GROUPBOX        "Elders ...",IDC_STATIC,6,7,132,188
    LISTBOX         IDC_LIST_BOOKSTUDY,12,18,120,147,LBS_SORT | LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
    PUSHBUTTON      "Add",IDC_BUTTON_ADD_GROUP,12,172,35,18
    PUSHBUTTON      "Edit",IDC_BUTTON_EDIT_ELDER,55,172,35,18
    PUSHBUTTON      "Delete",IDC_BUTTON_DELETE_GROUP,97,172,35,18
    GROUPBOX        "Publishers ...",IDC_STATIC,144,7,132,188
    LISTBOX         IDC_LIST_ELDERY_INFIRM,150,18,120,147,LBS_SORT | LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
    PUSHBUTTON      "Add",IDC_BUTTON_ADD_ELDERLY,150,172,35,18
    PUSHBUTTON      "Edit",IDC_BUTTON_EDIT_ELDERLY,193,172,35,18
    PUSHBUTTON      "Delete",IDC_BUTTON_DELETE_ELDERLY,235,172,35,18
    GROUPBOX        "Report Settings ...",IDC_STATIC,281,7,132,188
    LTEXT           "Starting month:",IDC_STATIC,286,18,120,8
    COMBOBOX        IDC_COMBO_MONTH,286,31,120,12,CBS_DROPDOWNLIST | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
    LTEXT           "Number of months:",IDC_STATIC,286,49,78,12
    COMBOBOX        IDC_COMBO_NUM_MONTHS,376,49,30,96,CBS_DROPDOWNLIST | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
    LTEXT           "Number of publishers to visit each month:",IDC_STATIC_NUM_PUB,286,65,84,18
    COMBOBOX        IDC_COMBO_PUB_PER_MONTH,376,66,30,12,CBS_DROPDOWNLIST | CBS_SORT | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
    LTEXT           "Starting publisher:",IDC_STATIC,286,90,120,8
    COMBOBOX        IDC_COMBO_PUBLISHER,286,103,120,12,CBS_DROPDOWNLIST | CBS_SORT | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
END
```

It is correctly set up as a page and I have initially set the control data via the IDE:

```
IDD_PAGE_ELDERLY_INFIRM AFX_DIALOG_LAYOUT
BEGIN
    0,
    0, 0, 0, 100,
    0, 0, 0, 100,
    0, 100, 0, 0,
    0, 100, 0, 0,
    0, 100, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 100,
    0, 0, 0, 100,
    0, 100, 0, 0,
    0, 100, 0, 0,
    0, 100, 0, 0,
    100, 0, 0, 100,
    100, 0, 0, 0,
    100, 0, 0, 0,
    100, 0, 0, 0,
    100, 0, 0, 0,
    100, 0, 0, 0,
    100, 0, 0, 0,
    100, 0, 0, 0,
    100, 0, 0, 0
END
```

I have adjusted my `CDialog` application to invoke the property sheet instead. The sheet itself sizes:

[image: Sheet]

Why is the sheet control not automatically resizing? I just don't get it. My other application uses the same base class and yet all those property pages correctly resizing the controls etc using the dynamic layout features.

## Update

I added this to one of my pages:

```
void CElderlyInfirmPage::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
{
    CMFCPropertyPage::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);

    AfxMessageBox(_T("Size"));

    // TODO: Add your message handler code here
    auto pManager = GetDynamicLayout();
    if (pManager != nullptr)
    {
        AfxMessageBox(_T("Valid"));
    }
}
```

It confirms that the "page" does not actually have a dynamic layout manager. Only the sheet does. So I think the problem is the fact that we can't use dynamic layout mechanism.

## Update 2

I made some progress. Example:

[image: Resized]

It turns out that the property page doesn't seem to load the dynamic layout resources like it does for a dialog. I started to create it manually:

```
BOOL CElderlyInfirmPage::OnInitDialog()
{
    CMFCPropertyPage::OnInitDialog();

    // TODO:  Add extra initialization here
    ReadSettings();
    InitMonthCombo();

    // Init to THIS month
    COleDateTime    datNow = COleDateTime::GetCurrentTime();
    m_cbMonth.SetCurSel(datNow.GetMonth()-1);

    EnableDynamicLayout(TRUE);
    auto pManager = GetDynamicLayout();
    if (pManager != nullptr)
    {
        pManager->Create(this);
        pManager->AddItem(IDC_COMBO_MONTH, CMFCDynamicLayout::MoveHorizontal(100), CMFCDynamicLayout::SizeNone());
        pManager->AddItem(IDC_COMBO_NUM_MONTHS, CMFCDynamicLayout::MoveHorizontal(100), CMFCDynamicLayout::SizeNone());
        pManager->AddItem(IDC_COMBO_PUB_PER_MONTH, CMFCDynamicLayout::MoveHorizontal(100), CMFCDynamicLayout::SizeNone());
        pManager->AddItem(IDC_COMBO_PUBLISHER, CMFCDynamicLayout::MoveHorizontal(100), CMFCDynamicLayout::SizeNone());
    }

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE unless you set the focus to a control
    // EXCEPTION: OCX Property Pages should return FALSE
}
```

As you can see, the controls move now so it is progress. But the problem now is that I have a lot of `IDC_STATIC` controls on these pages and I don't want to change the ID numbers. This is because the application already has translations for localization and if I change the ID values I blow up the translations. So I am wondering if I can use the `[CMFCDynamicLayout::LoadResource][3]` method to load the complete settings from the RC file. But I can't work out how to call `LoadResource` here. I am sure it would be the answer to this question.

## Update 3

I just traced the code and if you look here:

```
LRESULT CPropertySheet::HandleInitDialog(WPARAM, LPARAM)
{
    LRESULT lResult = OnInitDialog();

    CMFCDynamicLayout* pDynamicLayout = GetDynamicLayout();
    if (pDynamicLayout != NULL)
    {
        CRect rectWindow;
        GetWindowRect(rectWindow);
        m_sizeMin = rectWindow.Size();

        for (CWnd *pChild = GetWindow(GW_CHILD); pChild->GetSafeHwnd() != NULL; pChild = pChild->GetWindow(GW_HWNDNEXT))
        {
            HWND hwndChild = pChild->GetSafeHwnd();
            if (!pDynamicLayout->HasItem(hwndChild))
            {
                if (pChild->SendMessage(WM_GETDLGCODE) & DLGC_BUTTON)
                {
                    pDynamicLayout->AddItem(hwndChild, CMFCDynamicLayout::MoveHorizontalAndVertical(100, 100), CMFCDynamicLayout::SizeNone());
                }
                else if (IsLeftNavigationPane(hwndChild))
                {
                    pDynamicLayout->AddItem(hwndChild, CMFCDynamicLayout::MoveNone(), CMFCDynamicLayout::SizeVertical(100));
                }
                else if (DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(CPropertyPage, pChild) == NULL || CanAddPageToDynamicLayout())
                {
                    pDynamicLayout->AddItem(hwndChild, CMFCDynamicLayout::MoveNone(), CMFCDynamicLayout::SizeHorizontalAndVertical(100, 100));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return lResult;
}
```

It does not seem to actually work with the layout properly.

I tried to use:

```
LoadDynamicLayoutResource(m_lpszTemplateName);
```

And I traced it. It eventually ended up here:

```
BOOL CMFCDynamicLayout::LoadResource(CWnd* pHostWnd, LPVOID lpResource, DWORD dwSize)
{
    if (pHostWnd->GetSafeHwnd() == NULL || !::IsWindow(pHostWnd->GetSafeHwnd()) || lpResource == NULL)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    CMFCDynamicLayoutData layoutData;
    BOOL bResult = layoutData.ReadResource(lpResource, (UINT)dwSize);
    layoutData.ApplyLayoutDataTo(pHostWnd, FALSE);

    return bResult;
}
```

It failed on the `ApplyLayoutDataTo` call, on the first `if` statement:

```
BOOL CMFCDynamicLayoutData::ApplyLayoutDataTo(CWnd* pHostWnd, BOOL bUpdate)
{
    if (pHostWnd->GetSafeHwnd() == NULL || m_listCtrls.IsEmpty())
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    ASSERT_VALID(pHostWnd);

    pHostWnd->EnableDynamicLayout(FALSE);
    pHostWnd->EnableDynamicLayout();
```

`m_listCtrls.IsEmpty()` was empty. So it hadn't read it in properly anyway.

I think I have no choice but to assign IDs to all my controls, even the static ones and manually build the dynamic layout up. Unless you have other ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic layout is already be enabled for all classes derived from `CDialog` which call the default `CDialog::OnInitDialog`, which in turn uses `CMFCDynamicLayout::LoadResource` to read resizing information for child controls.

That include `CMFCPropertyPage`. The information is already loaded, so if you call `EnableDynamicLayout` it deletes the existing object and creates a new one. Just remove the call to `EnableDynamicLayout`.

This way `pManager->Create(this);` won't be necessary, but you can keep it in there. It won't do anything because `pManager` already created and the method knows not to create twice.

`CPropertySheet` does require `EnableDynamicLayout` and `pManager->Create`. PropertySheet cannot be designed in dialog editor, so MFC ignores resizing for its child windows. Dynamic resizing has to be implemented manually.

MCVE:

```
class CMyPage : public CMFCPropertyPage
{
    CButton bn;
    BOOL OnInitDialog()
    {
        CMFCPropertyPage::OnInitDialog();

        //add test button dynamically
        bn.Create(L"Test", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, CRect(0, 0, 100, 30), this, 301);

        auto pManager = GetDynamicLayout();
        if(pManager != nullptr)
        {
            pManager->AddItem(bn.GetDlgCtrlID(),
              CMFCDynamicLayout::MoveHorizontal(100),
              CMFCDynamicLayout::SizeNone());
        }
        return TRUE;
    }
};

class CMySheet :public CMFCPropertySheet
{
public:
    CMyPage Page1;
    CMySheet()
    {
        Page1.Construct(IDD_PAGE1);
        AddPage(&Page1);
    }

    static int CALLBACK XmnPropSheetCallback(HWND hWnd, UINT message, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        extern int CALLBACK AfxPropSheetCallback(HWND, UINT message, LPARAM lParam);
        // XMN: Call MFC's callback
        int nRes = AfxPropSheetCallback(hWnd, message, lParam);
        if (message == PSCB_PRECREATE)
            ((LPDLGTEMPLATE)lParam)->style |= (DS_3DLOOK | DS_SETFONT
                | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_SYSMENU | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION);
        return nRes;
    }

    BOOL OnInitDialog()
    {
        BOOL res = CMFCPropertySheet::OnInitDialog();
        EnableDynamicLayout(TRUE);//required for propertysheet
        auto pManager = GetDynamicLayout();
        if(pManager)
        {
            pManager->Create(this);
            for(CWnd *child = GetWindow(GW_CHILD); 
              child; child = child->GetWindow(GW_HWNDNEXT))
            {
                if(child->SendMessage(WM_GETDLGCODE) & DLGC_BUTTON)
                    pManager->AddItem(*child, 
                      CMFCDynamicLayout::MoveHorizontalAndVertical(100, 100),
                      CMFCDynamicLayout::SizeNone());
                else
                    pManager->AddItem(*child, 
                      CMFCDynamicLayout::MoveNone(),
                      CMFCDynamicLayout::SizeHorizontalAndVertical(100, 100));
            }
        }

        return res;
    }

    INT_PTR DoModal()
    {
        // Hook into property sheet creation code
        m_psh.dwFlags |= PSH_USECALLBACK;
        m_psh.pfnCallback = XmnPropSheetCallback;
        return CMFCPropertySheet::DoModal();
    }
};

...
CMySheet sh;
sh.DoModal();
```

Comment: I will try. What about using LoadResource?

Comment: I still had to have the `EnableDynamicLayout(TRUE);` call else the manager is `null`. I moved it to before the  line you stated. But I still have to manually add the controls. So I would like to use `LoadResource` if possible.

Comment: I still had to use the `Create` call else I got an assertion. I should explain that this project is several years old and I have just started to use it in 2017. But i can't see any other lines of code I may need.

Comment: Is this modal or modeless propertysheet? Note that calling `EnableDynamicLayout` is required in `CPropertySheet`, but it's not required in `CPropertyPage`, in fact you should avoid calling it after `OnInitDialog`. See the MSVE version in edit.

Comment: This is model. The sheet is my main window. If I don’t call it in the page then I have no manager and nothing moves.

Comment: Ah. I notice you call Construct. I have not been doing that. I will try later. 

Comment: You might not need `Construct`. There are different ways of opening the property sheet, your way obviously works. Just try the whole example to see if resizing works.

Comment: I will try later this morning. Got my first work shift in a minute.

Comment: Can I just ask though ... if you add a control to your page via the ide resources rather than dynamically does it still work?

Comment: Yes it works in my example. `CMFCDynamicLayout::LoadResource` is called automatically in `CMFCPropertyPage::OnInitDialog()`

Comment: It seems to be my base class. I started a new project, used your base class (with a bit of modification) and copied over my resources and they work! So I just got to port everything over to the new project. At least the translations should be Ok as I used the original resource.h file. Thanks.